# get data by string with bloc in flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, bloc

I am new in flutter.And i need help.
I have servise.I search data by string which i pass from Ui.

```
Future<List<MyEntity>> getByString(String s) async {
    final CollectionReference _dbs = Firestore.instance.collection(_baseUrl);
    QuerySnapshot query =
        await _dbs.where("string", isEqualTo: s).getDocuments();
    List<MyEntity> products = query.documents
        .map((doc) => MyEntity.fromSnapshotJson(doc))
        .toList();
    return products;
  }
```

And i have bloc.I dont know how can i pass string to sink from Ui?.

```
class MyBloc extends BlocBase {

  final MyService _productService;

  MyBloc(this._productService) {
    listEvent.add(await _productService.getByString(// i should pass string from Ui));
  }

  final BehaviorSubject<List<MyEntity>> _controller =
      new BehaviorSubject<List<MovieEntity>>.seeded(List<MyEntity>());

  Observable<List<MovieEntity>> get listFlux => _controller.stream;
  Sink<List<MovieEntity>> get listEvent => _controller.sink;

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controller?.close();
    super.dispose();
  }
}
```

Is it nice idea to initialize service in bloc constructor?Could you give me same advise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create an instance of the bloc inside you service class if you want the sink of the bloc and over there add values in the sink. 
So for example you have your service class than instantiate the block in init state and do remember to close it in dispose() like this:

```
class Service extends StatefullWidget{
@override
  _ServiceState createState() => _ServiceState();
}

class _ServiceState extends State<Service> {
  MyBloc _myBloc;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _myBloc = MyBloc();
    super.initState();
  }

 @override
  void dispose() {
    _myBloc?.close();
    super.dispose();
  }

Future<List<MyEntity>> getByString(String s) async {
    final CollectionReference _dbs = Firestore.instance.collection(_baseUrl);
    QuerySnapshot query =
        await _dbs.where("string", isEqualTo: s).getDocuments();
    List<MyEntity> products = query.documents
        .map((doc) => MyEntity.fromSnapshotJson(doc))
        .toList();
    return products;
  }
```

Now in Service class wherever you want to pass string just call

```
List<MyEntity> products = await getByString("search string");
_myBloc.listEvent.add(products);
```

and just modify your MyBloc code since it does not require service in its constructor like:

```
class MyBloc extends BlocBase {

  final BehaviorSubject<List<MyEntity>> _controller =
      new BehaviorSubject<List<MovieEntity>>.seeded(List<MyEntity>());

  Observable<List<MovieEntity>> get listFlux => _controller.stream;
  Sink<List<MovieEntity>> get listEvent => _controller.sink;

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controller?.close();
    super.dispose();
  }
}
```